# Showing custom alert message after quote updated in Magento 2

Tags: quote, magento2.3

I am trying to show the custom alert message after quote updated, for these, I have overwritten the **ajaxSubmit** method from `catalog-add-to-cart.js` file like below.

```
$.ajax({
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: formData,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,

                /** @inheritdoc */
                beforeSend: function () {
                    if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                        $('body').trigger(self.options.processStart);
                    }
                },

                /** @inheritdoc */
                success: function (res) {
                    var eventData, parameters;

                    $(document).trigger('ajax:addToCart', {
                        'sku': form.data().productSku,
                        'productIds': productIds,
                        'form': form,
                        'response': res
                    });

                    if (self.isLoaderEnabled()) {
                        $('body').trigger(self.options.processStop);
                    }

                    if (res.backUrl) {
                        eventData = {
                            'form': form,
                            'redirectParameters': []
                        };
                        // trigger global event, so other modules will be able add parameters to redirect url
                        $('body').trigger('catalogCategoryAddToCartRedirect', eventData);

                        if (eventData.redirectParameters.length > 0) {
                            parameters = res.backUrl.split('#');
                            parameters.push(eventData.redirectParameters.join('&'));
                            res.backUrl = parameters.join('#');
                        }

                        self._redirect(res.backUrl);

                        return;
                    }

                    if (res.messages) {
                        $(self.options.messagesSelector).html(res.messages);
                    }

                    if (res.minicart) {
                        $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
                        $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
                    }

                    if (res.product && res.product.statusText) {
                        $(self.options.productStatusSelector)
                            .removeClass('available')
                            .addClass('unavailable')
                            .find('span')
                            .html(res.product.statusText);
                    }
                    self.enableAddToCartButton(form);
                },

                /** @inheritdoc */
                complete: function (res) {
                    if (res.state() === 'rejected') {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
```

after completing these I have written below code to show the Custom Alert.

```
$.ajax({

                url: 'http://192.168.10.144/magento23/test',
                data: {},
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(res) {
                    alert(res);
                }

            });
```

But when I debugged my code in controller quote is not updated. Is there any possibility to get quote data on here? or I went wrong?

Suggest us to show the alert message after updated quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this, you can create a template and add it in footer by following below steps.

File: view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\AjaxAddtoCart" name="custom.ajaxcart" template="[Vendor]_[Module]::customajaxcart.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then create a block file.
File: Block/AjaxAddtoCart.php

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\Module\Block;

class AjaxAddtoCart extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

}
```

Then create a template file
File: view/frontend/templates/customajaxcart.phtml

```
<script>
require(['jquery', 'mage/url'], function($, url){
    $(document).on('ajax:addToCart', function(event, data) {
        alert('event fired');
        // do your custom code here
        $.ajax({
            showLoader: false,
            url: url.build('[your_route]/[controller]/[action]'),
            type: "GET"
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data.itemscount);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Now whenever you add product to cart from listing or detail page, this event will be fired when product has been added to cart using ajax functionality.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Well, let's try this.

Comment: Yeah !! Let me know if that works !!

Comment: The event is working, but when I used to get the quote information it's returning 0 items. For these I used ` $this->_cartData->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems()` code in block file

Comment: Just edited the phtml file content related to javascript. Cart items cannot be get through block file. You need to make another ajax call where you need to create some more files related to frontend route and controller. Controller should return json data of cart as per your needs. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Got it let's try with creating controller and return some thing.

Comment: Perfect, let me know the outcome !!!

Comment: Thats great !!! Enjoy !!! :)